# Consumer is not authorized to access %resources for Magento2 rest API

Tags: magento2

I created a new customer and got the token perfectly but when I try to access any API like

```
http://myhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me?Authorization=Bearerhy23vc01x9s1jd2t8gho47g58trllc0b
```

got the error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>
<parameters>
<resources>self</resources>
</parameters>
  <trace>#0 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(70): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator-&gt;checkPermissions()
#1 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator-&gt;validate()
#2 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver-&gt;resolve()
#3 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;processApiRequest()
#4 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http-&gt;launch()
#7 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-&gt;run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}</trace>
</response>
```

please any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Authorization token is NOT place on the parameter. Should be set on header instead. Here is an example on POSTMAN:

[image]

On cURL, it will be:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXX" "http://yoursite.com/rest/V1/products/:sku"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, already I tried it on headers or as parameters in url and works perfectly for some api like `products` as you did and `categories`, but for some APIs like `V1/customers/me`, I got the error. Even if i run the curl on terminal, it works perfectly. I use postman and http requester for firefox.

Comment: No problems on my testing site. Did you have a space between "Bearer" and the token? And maybe your token is expired, try to get a new one

Comment: HHH, What is a joke !! there was no space and worked fine in `products` and `categories` as I mentioned, but when removed it in `customers/me` worked fine. Please edit the answer and add the part of remove space to give it the true answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it's more likely to be token expired. I use the old token to access the API, it shows the same error you stated on question. Just renew the token and the problem solved.

Comment: @Jsparo30 did you found the solution i am also facing same issue