# Magento 2 rest API not working in online server

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm trying to integrate Magento REST API web service, but it answers me always:

> {"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Backend::store"}}

I'm creating an integration and generating the keys, and locally all runs fine, but when I put it online, the communication doesn't work.

This is the result with postman:

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150190/consumer-is-not-authorized-to-access-resources-for-magento2-rest-api

Comment: it still doesn't work. it gives me allways the same anwser: Consumer is not authorized, it doesn't matter if i make the request with authorization with user and password, or with keys

Comment: How about if you use admin credential to login?

Comment: I've already tested that too, with the same result.

Comment: How about other APIs, such as Customer, Catalog?

Comment: Cant access to none of them, always the same answer

Comment: Try to compare the settings between Dev and production. That's really strange...

Comment: I included a picture of the result with a call made with postman.

Comment: I've already compare the configurations of php and apache and can't find differences. My server uses Centos 7, does someone know if it needs some kind of special configuration?